# ASP.NET Identity using Peta Poco

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am starting to learn the `ASP.NET Identity` framework which we will include in our project as a replacement for our current `ASP.NET MembershipProvider`.

We use a `SQL Server database` and `Peta Poco` as our micro-orm, and we use the database first approach. We have a `Users` table which contains username, email, password, ...

I read that ASP.NET Identity uses the Code first approach together with Entity Framework.

How can we implement this framework in our project? Or is this not possible unless we use EF?

Comment: try [this tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/), i already converted [NHibernate.AspNet.Identity](https://github.com/milesibastos/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity) to PetaPoco. The only thing lost is the **IQueryableUserStore** (don't know why the previous answer was deleted....)